# want to change time period in week view of fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) plugin.I did code for week view default display 3 day at a time but i want to display 15 min time slot duration
for example 9.00 to 9.15. This is what I tried:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        center: 'agendaThreeDay' // buttons for switching between views
    },
    views: {
        agendaThreeDay: {

        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 3 },
        buttonText: '3 day'
    }
},
defaultView:'agendaThreeDay'
});
```

my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z0au4L8x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem for you:

```
select: function(start, end) {
    console.log( 'Events :' + getEventsByTime( start, end ).length );
    var ev = getEventsByTime( start, end );
    console.log( ev );
    var itms = {};            

    ev.forEach(function(entry){

      var begin = moment(entry.start);
      var final = moment(entry.end);


    while( begin.diff(final) < 0 ) {
        itms[begin] =  ( itms[begin] || 0) + 1;
        if( itms[begin] >= maxEventsInInterval ) {
            console.log(' __ WARNING __ , max events exceeded! ');
        }

        begin = moment(begin).add('seconds', 900);
    }

});
    console.log( itms );
}

function getEventsByTime( start, stop ) {
    var todaysEvents = $('div[name=calendar]').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {

       return ( 
           ( event.start >= start && event.end <= stop ) || 
           ( start >= event.start && stop <= event.end)  || 
           (start <= event.start && stop >= event.start) ||
           (start >= event.start && start <= event.end)
       );
    });
    return todaysEvents;
}
```